# Send Report in Email in oracle apex

Tags: email, report, oracle-apex

I looking to send the report or the Table as an attachment in the email, in oracle apex I have tried it show this error

```
ORA-20001: The printing engine could not be reached because either the URL specified is incorrect or a proxy URL needs to be specified. for Execute PL/SQL Code.
```

here is the code

```
DECLARE
    l_id number;
    l_document BLOB;
BEGIN
    l_document := apex_util.get_print_document (
        p_application_id      => 127,
        p_report_query_name   => 'CatpbReport',
        p_report_layout_name  => 'CatpbReport',
        p_report_layout_type  => 'XSL-FO',
        p_document_format     => 'pdf'  );
 
   l_id := APEX_MAIL.SEND(
       p_to        => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
       p_from      => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
       p_subj      => 'sending PDF by using print API',
       p_body      => 'Please review the attachment.',
       p_body_html => 'Please review the attachment');
 
   APEX_MAIL.ADD_ATTACHMENT (
       p_mail_id    => l_id,
       p_attachment => l_document,
       p_filename   => 'mydocument.pdf',
       p_mime_type  => 'application/pdf'
   );
END;
```

i don't know why it's not working for me when I tried in the SQL command it sends the email, when I attach in the dynamic action it shows this as an error.

Answer (score 0):

don't you need printing server to use it?

not an answer to your question but as an alternative:

you can create html, doc, csv by hand, convert it to blob and add it as an attachment to your email.

create lob,

```
dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => l_body_blob, cache => true, dur =>dbms_lob.call);
```

then convert your clob to blob

```
dbms_lob.converttoblob (
    dest_lob    => l_body_blob,
    src_clob    => l_body_clob,
    amount      => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize,
    dest_offset => l_dest_offset,
    src_offset  => l_source_offset,
    blob_csid   => dbms_lob.default_csid,
    lang_context=> l_lang_context,
    warning     => l_warning);
```

then add it to your mail & send

```
l_mail_id := 
    apex_mail.send (
        p_to           => 'foo@bar.nl',
        p_from         => 'goo@bar.nl',                 
        p_body         => l_body,
        p_body_html    => l_body,
        p_subj         => l_subject);

apex_mail.add_attachment(l_mail_id, l_body_blob, 'test.doc', 'application/msword');
```

optionally:

```
apex_mail.push_queue;
```

this way you should get an email with a DOC attachment.